# Alternative for absolute url when loading assets (Insecure resource )

Tags: symfony, twig

I have an `iframe` inside a Twig template file that displays the content of a PDF file like this:

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/gview?url={{ absolute_url(asset('bundles/path/to/file.pdf')) }}&embedded=true"></iframe>
```

But when opening the iframe, Chrome displays this error message:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://website.com/home#pdf' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://docs.google.com/gview?url=pdf/url?v2249&embedded=true'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

What other option can I use?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
{{ app.request.scheme ~'://' ~ app.request.httpHost ~ asset('bundles/path/to/file.pdf') }}
```

But **preferred** option is

```
{{ app.request.getSchemeAndHttpHost() ~ asset('bundles/path/to/file.pdf') }}
```

So the ready solution will be following:

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/gview?url={{ app.request.getSchemeAndHttpHost() ~ asset('bundles/path/to/file.pdf') }}&embedded=true"></iframe>
```

Comment: how about this part: `https://docs.google.com/gview?url=` ?  Do I keep it before the `{{}}` ?

Comment: This is still giving me a `GET http://localhost:35729/livereload.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` and inside the iframe, I get a "no preview avaible" message

Comment: What is an URL generated in the iframe?